# How can I change data value from one component to another component in Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new in Vue Js. So, I am facing a problem to changes data value from another component.

I have a component A:

```
<template>
   <div id="app">
      <p v-on:click="test ()">Something</p>
   </div>
</template>

import B from '../components/B.vue';
export default {
    components: {
        B
    },
    methods: {
        test: function() {
            B.data().myData = 124
            B.data().isActive = true
            console.log(B.data().myData);
            console.log(B.data().isActive);
        }
    }
}
```

Component B:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            myData: 123,
            isActive: false

        }
    }

}
```

It still component B data.
But it cannot be affected component B data. I want to data changes of component B from component A. How can I do that?

Please explain me in details. I have seen vue js props attribute but I don't understand.

Comment: can you update which is component A and component B?

Comment: I updated my code. Please see and answer me.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex).

It's the centralized store for all the data in your applications.

Take a look at their documentation, it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I think this is the right answer to the proposed question.  The other solution moves the data and data drivers into component A and assumes component B is only a display component.  I think the question is more akin to component A as a layout which may include some action buttons, and component B is where all the data is stored and transformation occurs.  Vuex solves for this situation.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass down props to the component B. These props can be updated by the parent component. You can think of B as a stupid component that just renders what the parent tells it to rendern. Example:

```
// Component A
<template>
   <div id="app">
      <p v-on:click="test ()">Something</p>
      <b data="myData" isActive="myIsActive"></b>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import B from '../components/B.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    B
  },
  data() {
    return {
      myData: 0,
      myIsActive: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    test: function() {
      this.myData = 123
      this.myIsActive = true
    }
  }
}
</script>

// Component B
<template>
  <div>{{ data }}{{ isActive }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    data: Number,
    isActive: Boolean
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways...

1. if your components have a parent child relationship you can pass data values from parent into child.
2. If your want to communicate back to parent component when child component has changed something, you can use vuejs event emitter(custom event) to emit a event when data value change and that event can be listened in another component and do what you want.
3. If your components doesn't have a relationship, then you have to use use something else than above things. You can use two things.one is event bus, other one is state management library.for vue there is a official state management library called VueX.it is very easy to use.if you want to use something else than vuex, you can use it such as redux, mobx etc.

This documentation has everything what you want to know. I don't want to put any code, because of doc is very clear.

VueX is the most preferable way to do this! Very easy to use..

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Hello from the future. With Vue3, Pinia is the officially-recommended global store. VueX seems very obtuse in hindsight.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//component A
Vue.component('my-button', {
  props: ['title'],
  template: `<button v-on:click="$emit('add-value')">{{title}}</button>`
});


Vue.component('my-viewer', {
  props: ['counter'],
  template: `<button>{{counter}}</button>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    counter: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething: function() {
      this.counter++;
    }
  }
})


Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['title'],
  template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>'
});

//parent
new Vue({
  el: '#blog-post-demo',
  data: {
    posts: [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'My journey with Vue'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Blogging with Vue'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Why Vue is so fun'
      }
    ]
  }
});


Vue.component('blog-post2', {
  props: ['post'],
  template: `
                  <div class="blog-post">
                     <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                     <button v-on:click="$emit('enlarge-text')">
                         Enlarge text
                     </button>
                     <div v-html="post.content"></div>
                 </div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#blog-posts-events-demo',
  data: {
    posts: [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'My journey with Vue'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Blogging with Vue'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Why Vue is so fun'
      }
    ],
    postFontSize: 1
  },
  methods: {
    onEnlargeText: function() {
      this.postFontSize++;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<p>Two components adding & viewing value</p>
<div id="app">
  <my-button :title="'Add Value'" v-on:add-value="doSomething"></my-button>
  <my-viewer :counter="counter"></my-viewer>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<p>Passing Data to Child Components with Props (Parent to Child)</p>
<div id="blog-post-demo">
  <blog-post v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id" v-bind:title="post.title"></blog-post>
</div>

<p>Listening to Child Components Events (Child to Parent)</p>
<div id="blog-posts-events-demo">
  <div :style="{ fontSize: postFontSize + 'em' }">
    <blog-post2 v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id" v-bind:post="post" v-on:enlarge-text="onEnlargeText"></blog-post2>
  </div>
</div>
```

First, you need a parent so two component can communicate. when `my-button` component is clicked triggers an event `add-value` that calls `doSomething()` function, then updates the value & show it to `my-viewer` component.

**HTML**

```
     <!--PARENT-->
     <div id="app"> 
          <!--CHILD COMPONENTS-->
          <my-button :title="'Add Value'" v-on:add-value="doSomething"></my-button>
          <my-viewer :counter="counter"></my-viewer>
     </div>
```

**VUE.JS**

```
     //component A
     Vue.component('my-button',{
         props:['title'],
         template:`<button v-on:click="$emit('add-value')">{{title}}</button>`
     });

     //Component B
     Vue.component('my-viewer',{
        props:['counter'],
        template:`<button>{{counter}}</button>`
     });

     //Parent
     new Vue({
         el: '#app',
         data:{
            counter:0,
         },
         methods:{
             doSomething:function(){
               this.counter++;
             }
        }
     })
```

This is base on [Vue Components Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

**Passing Data to Child Components with Props (Parent to Child)**

**VUE.JS**

```
         //component (child)
         //Vue component must come first, else it won't work
         Vue.component('blog-post', {
             /*Props are custom attributes you can register on a component. When a 
               value is passed to a prop attribute, it becomes a property on that 
               component instance*/
             props: ['title'],
             template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>'
         });

         //parent
         new Vue({
            el: '#blog-post-demo',
            data: {
              posts: [
                 { id: 1, title: 'My journey with Vue' },
                 { id: 2, title: 'Blogging with Vue' },
                 { id: 3, title: 'Why Vue is so fun' }
              ]
            }
         });
```

**HTML:**

`v-for` will loop on posts and pass data to `blog-post` component

```
         <div id="blog-post-demo">
             <blog-post  v-for="post in posts"
                         v-bind:key="post.id"
                         v-bind:title="post.title"></blog-post>
         </div>
```

**Listening to Child Components Events (Child to Parent)**

**HTML**

You must first register the event by `v-on:enlarge-text="onEnlargeText"` to use `$emit` and make sure that it's always set to lower case or it won't work properly. example `enlargeText` and `Enlargetext` will always be converted to `enlargetext`, thus use enlarge-text instead, because its easy to read & valid, for a brief explanation about `$emit` you can read it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

```
         <div id="blog-posts-events-demo">
            <div :style="{ fontSize: postFontSize + 'em' }">
                 <blog-post
                          v-for="post in posts"
                          v-bind:key="post.id"
                          v-bind:post="post"
                          v-on:enlarge-text="onEnlargeText"></blog-post>
            </div>
         </div>
```

**VUE.JS**

When user clicks the `button` the `v-on:click="$emit('enlarge-text')"` will trigger then calling the function `onEnlargeText()` in the parent

```
         //component (child)
         Vue.component('blog-post', {
             props: ['post'],
             template: `
              <div class="blog-post">
                 <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                 <button v-on:click="$emit('enlarge-text')">
                     Enlarge text
                 </button>
                 <div v-html="post.content"></div>
             </div>`
         })

         //parent
         new Vue({
            el: '#blog-posts-events-demo',
            data: {
               posts: [
                    { id: 1, title: 'My journey with Vue' },
                    { id: 2, title: 'Blogging with Vue' },
                    { id: 3, title: 'Why Vue is so fun' }
               ],
            postFontSize: 1
         },
         methods:{
            onEnlargeText:function(){
               this.postFontSize++;
            }
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually props suck sometimes you got some old external library in jquyer and need just damn pass value. in 99% of time use props that do job but.

A) spend tons of hours debuging changing tones of code to pass variables
B) one line solution

Create main variable in data letmeknow as object {}

> this.$root.letmeknow

then somewhere in code from component

> this.$root.letmeknow = this;

and then boom i got component console.log( this.$root.letmeknow  ) and see now can change some values